# Best way to plot large set of data from multiple files matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a very huge set of data which needs to be imported from different files and need to plot in one figure(at most 5 plots). Right now I am doing this in a for loop which is really slowing up the process. My idea is to make two matrices one contains 'x' values and another with 'y' values and finally plot. The data size is not the same. What is the best way to achieve this? Can this be done using arrayfun or vectorization?

Comment: What do you mean with huge? And share some of your current code, otherwise it is impossible to improve it ;)

Comment: the data size is ~ (30000*2)
Sample code:
   [Fn,Pn] = uigetfile('*.txt','multiselect','on')
   for i = 1:size(Fn,2)
      PD =   importdata(fullfile(Pn,Fn{i}),';',3);
      plot(PD.data(:,1),PD.data(:,2));
      hold on;
   end

Comment: What is slow? The file parsing or the plotting? Please add the relevant code to your question.